# The travelling salesman problem for a regular n-gon

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, graph-theory, polygons

The TSP asks, given a finite set $V$ of points in $\Bbb R^2$, to find the shortest path that passes through all points and returns to the starting point. Trivially, one reduces to the case of a path that consists only of straight lines between elements of $V$, but the resulting combinatorial problem is quite difficult in general, and TSP is known to be NP-complete.

However, it is solvable in many concrete cases, and I am sure that the $n$-gon is one of them. It is intuitively reasonable that the perimeter of a regular $n$-gon is the solution to TSP on the vertices, but how would you prove it?

Can the proof be generalized to any convex polygon?

Comment: Is the polygon embedded in Euclidean space? If the side lengths are free to take any value, then there is a counterexample. For a triangle with side lengths $1$, $1$, and $3$, the shortest path is *not* the perimeter.

Comment: @Kajelad: That polygon is not regular.

Comment: Right. It does mean that this statement can't be generalized to polygon graphs with arbitrary edge costs. I suspect your claim is true on arbitrary polygons so long as the Triangle Inequality holds.

Comment: @Kajelad I don't understand what generalization you are considering. A triangle with side lengths 1, 1, 3 doesn't even satisfy the triangle inequality, so it can't embed in any metric space (including all Euclidean spaces).

Comment: @Kajelad "your claim is true on arbitrary polygons so long as the Triangle Inequality holds" No, there is a counterexample with non-convex polygons. Take the nonconvex quadrilateral with vertices $(-1,0), (0,a), (1,0), (0,a+1)$ where $a\gg 1$. The perimeter is $\approx 4a$, but the ordering $(-1,0), (1,0), (0,a), (0,a+1)$ has perimeter $\approx 2a$.

Comment: My apologies, I must have misinterpreted the question. By "$n$-gon", I thought you meant a finite, weighted, undirected, connected graph of uniform degree $2$. I see now that you're talking about the complete graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a path $P$ through all the points in a convex polygon. It can be specified by enumerating the vertices it touches in order: $P=\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$.

1. **If it isn't the perimeter, it cuts itself at some point in the interior.** *Proof:* Take a segment $[v_i, v_{i+1}]$ that's not a side. It splits the polygon into two parts. They must be joined together by another segment for $P$ to be closed. Therefore, there's another segment that intersects it.
2. **Let $[v_i,v_{i+1}]$, $[v_j,v_{j+1}]$ be two segments that intersect. Then, the path obtained by exchanging $v_{i+1}$ and $v_j$ (that is, $P'=\{v_1,\dots,v_i,v_j,v_{j-1}\dots,v_{i+1},v_{j+1},v_{j+2},\dots,v_n\}$) is shorter than $P$.** *Proof:* The lengths of $P$ and $P'$ are the same except for the difference between $d(v_i,v_{i+1})+d(v_j,v_{j+1})$ and $d(v_i,v_j)+d(v_{i+1},v_{j+1})$. The second should be smaller because it uncrosses the segments.

It follows that the perimeter is the solution to the TSP for convex polygons, because for any other path you can uncross any two intersecting segments and get a shorter one.

---

*Note:* As stated in the comments, this proof works for non-degenerate convex polygons. In the degenerate case, we can remove the degenerate points and the solution for the resulting polygon will be a solution for the original one.

Comment: I discussed this problem with a friend, and we also came to the conclusion that the lemma in point (2) is crucial. Another way to state it is: In any convex quadrilateral (= with intersecting diagonals), the sum of the lengths of the diagonals is greater than the lengths of either pair of opposite sides. Proof: If the vertices are $ABCD$ and $E$ is the intersection of the diagonals, then $$|AC|+|BD|=|AE|+|EC|+|BE|+|BD|\le|AB|+|CD|$$ by the triangle inequality on triangles $ABE$ and $CDE$.

Comment: For point (1): It may be the case that the segment that is not a side is nevertheless on the boundary, because of collinear vertices. We can eliminate such degeneracies by proving it for nondegenerate polygons (no $180^\circ$ edges), and then given a degenerate vertex the corresponding TSP with this vertex removed will have to also pass through this point, so it is still a solution. Assuming nondegeneracy, the bad edge will pass through the interior, but maybe the path from one "part" to the other somehow goes around this segment. Convexity needs to apply here to exclude this case.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You're right. I will modify the answer to take into account the degenerate case.